# Implementing Spring oauth2 client datastore in a NoSQL database

Tags: spring, spring-security, nosql

I have a simple spring boot application setup with oauth 2.0 and client details are being fetched from mysql. I am looking for a way to implement client datastore in a NoSQL database. I am not really sure on how to implement this and I couldnt find any resources online for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend **AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter** class, there you configure **UserDetailsService** that uses your custom repository.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationConfigurationProperties configuration;

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

---

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        // get user and create UserDetails object from that
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


public class User {

    public String userName;
    public String password;

    public User() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

---

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    public Customer findByUserName(String firstName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks abzal. I was also looking to implement the client token details - client id, secret, scope, grant_type.

Comment: @Abhishek you can upvote or accept as answer. That is kind of thanks

Comment: @Afzal can you let me know how to implement the client details as well in nosql db

Comment: @Abhishek you have an example of clients storage in mongodb https://github.com/caelwinner/spring-security-mongo. I didn't try but it seems good